# Serializing with Json.NET: how to require a property not being null?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Using Newtonsoft's Json.NET serializer, is it possible to require a property to contain a non-null value and throw an exception on serialization if this not the case? Something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("bar", SerializationRequired = SerializationRequired.DisallowNull)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I know it is possible to do this upon deserialization (using the `Required` property of `JsonProperty`), but I cannot find anything on this for serialization.

Comment: Did you go trough this one http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm ? At the end it mentions you could add an internal OnError method to the Foo class, where you can specify the requested behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible by setting the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm) to [`Required.Always`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm).

This requires Newtonsoft 12.0.1+, which didn't exist at the time this question was asked.

The example below throws a `JsonSerializationException` ( "Required property 'Value' expects a value but got null. Path '', line 1, position 16." ):

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{'Value': null }";
    Demo res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Demo>(json);
}

class Demo
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The question was regarding serialization, not deserialization.

Comment: @Stmated: `Required.Always` applies to both.  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Demo());` also throws a `JsonSerializationException` (specifically, `Cannot write a null value for property 'Value'`).

Comment: I tried this with 13.0.1 just today, and it did not work. Well, unless it's a sort of feature-bug where the validation is not done if the NullValueHandling is set to Ignore. Which it was for me. That's a dealbreaker in that case.
EDIT: Yes. That was the case. So you were right, but it's not a good implementation.

Comment: @Stmated: Why would you expect validation of nulls to be done if you told Newtonsoft to ignore NullValueHandling?

Comment: Because I would expect the contract to be adhered to even if the serialization formatting is said to skip null values in the output. It is still practically null, just not a visible null.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Newtonsoft serialization error handling documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationerrorhandling.htm) you could handle the null atribute within an OnError() method. I am not entirely sure what would you pass to the SerializeObject() as a NullValueHandling parameter.

```
public class Foo
{
     [JsonProperty]
     public string Bar 
     {
         get 
         {
             if(Bar == null)
             {
                 throw new Exception("Bar is null");
             }
             return Bar;
         }
         set { Bar = value;}

     [OnError]
     internal void OnError(StreamingContext context, ErrorContext errorContext)
     {
          // specify that the error has been handled
          errorContext.Handled = true;
          // handle here, throw an exception or ...
     }
}


int main()
{
     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo(), 
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
                        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        });
}
```

Comment: Ha! That would work, but that's a lot of plumbing to make things happen... I'd rather write my own validator/validation attributes and call that before serializing!